# Dynamically setting the @GET statement with retrofit

Tags: android, api, get, retrofit

A sample request to an API is this

`https://api.example.com/api/3.0/song/{song_id}.json?apikey={your_api_key}`

So, in my activity

```
//retrofit
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(C.BASE_URL_DETAIL)     // "https://api.example.com/api/3.0/song/"                                           
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
SongInterface request = retrofit.create(SongInterface.class);
//call
Call<SongObject> call =request.getDetails(C.MY_API_KEY);
```

My interface for song id = 10973

```
@GET("10973.json?")
Call<SongObject> getDetails(
        @Query("apikey") String key
);
```

It works just fine and i receive the data as expected.  However, I can't figure out how to call another song with another id and reuse the code.  Can I somehow add the ID as a Query parameter? (the API doesn't seem to be set up to allow this).  How can I dynamically update the String to the interface inside the @GET.  My attempts to accomplish this have all ended with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there yes right it is absolutely correct way so send ***"GET"*** request and like you asked to get a data with respective id here is **how** you can achieve it

```
@GET("{songId}.json?")
 Call<SongObject> getDetails(
    @Path("songId") String songId, 
    @Query("apikey") String key
 );
```

After this you can call it simply you did it.

> **LIKE THIS**

```
Call<SongObject> call = request.getDetails(YOUR_SONG_ID,C.MY_API_KEY);
```

Comment: My pleasure pal